# How to test if a model was saved before passed on to task queue?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

In the following method the correct behaviour would to to save the `news` model **before** passing its id to the asynchronous Task queue for further processing.
Otherwise the task queue has the older version.

As you can see I have made a mistake and am saving the model after sending its id to the task queue.

```
def save_scraped_body_into_model(url_string):
        news = ndb.Key(urlsafe=url_string).get()
        ...
        news.body = result
        news.stage = 1
        taskqueue.Task(url='/api/v1.0/worker/bbc-stage-2', headers=header,
                           payload=json.dumps({'news_url_string': news.key.urlsafe()})).add(queue_name='newstasks')
        news.put()
```

How do I possibly test for that?
My test below passes as long as the model was saved. But thats wrong, the order matters, and this test doesn't capture it !!!  Is there a way to achieve this with mock?

```
def test_news_instance_saved_before_next_stage(self, get_head):
        BBCSpider.save_scraped_body_into_model(self.news.key.urlsafe())
        context = ndb.get_context()
        context.clear_cache()
        news = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.news.key.urlsafe()).get()
        self.assertEqual(news.stage, 1)
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm late but if you are still interested in I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm doing these kind of tests by using `patch` from [`unittest.mock` framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

When I need to do test like this the first thing I do is looking for a point where I can put a hook. Then I patch the hook and use `side_effect` callback to do the test.

In your case the hook will be `BBCSpider.taskqueue.Task` and its `side_effect` something like this:

```
lambda *args,**kwargs: self.assertEqual(1, ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.news.key.urlsafe()).get().stage)
```

So your test become:

```
@patch('BBCSpider.taskqueue.Task', autospec=True)
def test_news_instance_saved_before_next_stage(self, get_head, mock_task):
    def check_if_model_saved(*args,**kwargs):
        news = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.news.key.urlsafe()).get()
        self.assertEqual(news.stage,1)
    mock_task.side_effect = check_if_model_saved
    BBCSpider.save_scraped_body_into_model(self.news.key.urlsafe())
    self.assertTrue(mock_task.called)
```

Note `autospec=True` is not mandatory but I like to use it every time I do a patch to avoid silly errors.

I'm apologize if the code contains some mistake (I cannot test it without considerable effort) but I hope the idea is clear.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Thats very interesting approach. So even though I am saving `news.put()` at the end, because the mock.hook comes before, the `side_effect` of that hook would still see the model as unsaved?  Even though it was saved one line later?

Comment: Sure: `side_effect` (and so `self.assertEqual(news.stage,1)`) will be executed when your code call `taskqueue.Task()` and so **before** `news.put()` call